# JQuery, return integer for p element

Tags: jquery

Here is my rendered html:

`<h1 class="text-center"><p id='DA1'>34</p></h1>`

I want to return: 34 (as an integer)

I tried:

```
var DA1 = parseInt($("#DA1").text(),1);
```

with no success?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radix should be 10

```
var DA1 = parseInt($("#DA1").text(),10);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rF45T/)